# Php SMTP Error 10060 : FAILED TO CONNECT TO SERVER

Tags: php, html, smtp

I have php code to send email using SMTP connection; It was working perfectly 2 weeks ago. But suddenly stopped working. Don't know what the problem is.

> **SMTP -> ERROR**: FAILED TO CONNECT TO SERVER: A CONNECTION ATTEMPT
>   FAILED BECAUSE THE CONNECTED PARTY DID NOT PROPERLY RESPOND AFTER A
>   PERIOD OF TIME, OR ESTABLISHED CONNECTION FAILED BECAUSE CONNECTED
>   HOST HAS FAILED TO RESPOND. (10060)  SMTP ERROR: COULD NOT CONNECT TO
>   SMTP HOST.

```
//start  mailing function
require_once('PHPMailer_v5.1\class.phpmailer.php');
$mail  = new PHPMailer();   
$mail->IsSMTP();
//MAIL config
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->Host       = "localhost";      // set as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 25;
$mail->Username   = "myemail@web.com";  // localhost email username
$mail->Password   = "XXXX";            
//End mail config
$mail->From       = $sender_email;
$mail->FromName   = $sender_user_name;
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAddress($to,$to_name);
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
if(!$mail->Send()) {//to see if we return a message or a value bolean
    echo "<p>Confirmation Mail delivery failed due to invalid email specified !</p>";
}
```

Comment: is the port 25 open on your system and does <random firewall name here> allow connections to it?

Comment: @scones : As said, it was working fine with localhost and port 25; can not assume what went wrong!

Comment: Yes, i read that. My question was: Has something changed since "2 weeks ago"? If your source has not changed, the system must have.

Comment: @scones : My host provider upgraded Parallels Panel version! thats all. And i have asked them, connection details are correct

Comment: `$mail->Host       = "localhost"` this is your machine, not your provider. So again: is the Port 25 on your machine open? has your machine changed in any other way since "2 weeks ago"?

Comment: @scones : machine means, Google chrome ?

Comment: `localhost` refers to the computer the program is running on. if you actually have `localhost` in your source, try changing it to the correct url of your provider.

Comment: @scones : My host provide said to user Local host & port 25 ; they said its working from their end... asked me to check any problem with my code

Comment: 1.) Try to connect to the port using telnet (`telnet localhost 25`) from that system. Does that offer an smtp dialog or does that fail? If it fails: you smtp server has gone, whyever. 2.) if that succeeds: check the smtp servers log entries.

Comment: @scones : I am using internet browser to connect that system. How can i enter windows command there ? telnet localhost 25

Comment: ah, i see, your code is on a remote server. please try the `telnet www.yourserverdomain.com 25` arkascha mentioned.

Comment: @scones : i did, its replying as "220 ****************************************************************************
************"

Comment: 2.) if that succeeds: check the smtp servers log entries. – arkascha

Comment: @scones : Please let me know how to check server log entry ? and what doe you mean by arkascha ??

Comment: arkascha is the other commenter above. i just wanted to focus your attention on his debugging strategy, since it is correct. if you have no access to the mail server logs, you have to try using the domain u used for the telnet instead of "localhost" in the code shown above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23413/discussion-between-logan-and-scones)

Comment: @scones : is $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
that not enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to

```
$mail->Host       = "localhost";      // set as the SMTP server
```

I changed it to

```
$mail->Host       = "mail.web.com";      // set as the SMTP server
```

It works now!